# How can I change a slash to a hash in a URL with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-rewriting

I need to replace a slash with a hash in a URL. Everything else stays the same.
e.g.:
this:

```
www.example.com/main/events/event-1
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
www.example.com/main/events#event-1
```

(jQuery solution is optimal, plugins OK)

**Update based on OP's comment:**

Using this code:

```
function outputStatus(e)
{
  if (e.success && $.url.segment(1) == 'events')
  {
    // IF Flash SWF loads success AND on events page
    var url = $.url.attr('source'); // gets current URL
    var new_url = url.replace(/\/([^\/]+)$/, "#$1"); // replaces last slash with a hash
    window.location = new_url; // sets the current URL to the new URL
  }
}
```

The URL is getting changed twice (so `www.example.com/main/events/event-1` is becoming `www.example.com/main/events#event-1` and then `www.example.com/main#events#event-1`).

Answer (score 5):

No jQuery needed, Javascript has native string replacement methods.

```
var url = "www.example.com/main/events/event-1"
var new_url = url.replace(/\/([^\/]+)$/, "#$1");
alert(new_url);
```

`/\/([^\/]+)$/` will match the last slash and everything after it until the end of the string. `$1` in the second argument is a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to the group created in the pattern (which contains everything after the final slash). [Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/36W7Y/)!

---

**Update:**

My guess is that your `outputStatus` function is being called multiple times, and thus replacing multiple times. You can avoid this by checking for the presence of a `#` in your url first:

```
if (url.indexOf('#') == -1) // # is not found
{
  var new_url = url.replace(/\/([^\/]+)$/, "#$1");
}
```

[`String#indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp) will return a position if the value is found, and -1 if not.

Alternately (since it seems like you're using the [jQuery URL Parser](http://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser), correct?), you could check for the presence of `$.url.attr('anchor')` before modifying the `url` variable.

Comment: this works, but it gets done 2X. 

using window.location = new_url; URL is first changed to: 

www.example.com/main/events#event-1 

and then to: 

www.example.com/main#events#event-1 (2 hashes) 

just need it done 1X.

Comment: [code]
  function outputStatus(e) {
   if (e.success && $.url.segment(1) == 'events') {  // IF Flash SWF loads success AND on events page
    var url = $.url.attr('source'); // gets current URL
     var new_url = url.replace(/\/([^\/]+)$/, "#$1"); // replaces last slash with a hash
     window.location = new_url; //sets the current URL to the new URL
   }
  }
[/code]

Comment: (sorry about the line breaks, or lack thereof)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "www.example.com/main/events/event-1";

var idx = str.lastIndexOf('/');

var res = str.substr(0,idx) + '#' + str.substr(idx + 1);
```

or this:

```
var str = "www.example.com/main/events/event-1"

var res = str.replace(/\/([^/]+)$/,'#$1');
```